# Увеличить стабильность php кода

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Пытаюсь модифицировать элементы в `index.html` с помощью *php simple dom*

В данном случае хочу изменить в тэге `img` атрибут `src` на `/images/image.jpg`

```
$value = '/images/image.jpg';
echo $value;  // Выводит  /images/image.jpg
$htmlmod->find('img',0 )->src = $value;
echo $htmlmod->find('img',0 )->src;   //Выводит  /images/image.jpg


//Перезаписываем index.html
$filename = "index.html";
$file_handle = fopen($filename, "w");
fwrite($file_handle, $htmlmod); 
fclose($file_handle);
```

Проблема следующая: 
иногда функция срабатывает, а иногда просто не перезаписывается. Работает либо через раз, либо стабильно , либо потом опять чуть ли не каждый раз перезапись не работает. Помогите решить проблему, сам не понимая что тут не так =(

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить команду

```
fflush($file_handle);
```

перед *fclose()*.

При записи в файл функцией `fwrite()` данные помещаются в буфер записи, а не сразу записываются на диск. Функция `fflush()` выполняет принудительную запись файлового буфера на диск.

Такое поведение PHP обусловлено тем, что при закрытии сессии происходит автоматическое закрытие файлов. И оптимизатор работает таким образом, что неохранённые на диске данные могут при этом просто потеряться.

Comment: Можете поподробнее рассказать, что делает функция `fflush()` и как она решает проблему стабильности?